Why multiple key events does not work correctly in editor area?
I have this code:
    display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                String string = "";
                System.out.println("statemask: " + event.stateMask);
                System.out.println("keycode " + event.keyCode );
                //check click together?
                if ((event.stateMask & SWT.ALT) != 0) string += "ALT - keyCode = " + event.keyCode;
                if ((event.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) != 0) string += "CTRL - keyCode = " + event.keyCode;
                if ((event.stateMask & SWT.SHIFT) != 0) string += "SHIFT - keyCode = " + event.keyCode;
                
                if(event.keyCode == SWT.BS)
                {
                    string += "BACKSPACE - keyCode = " + event.keyCode;
                }
                
                if(event.keyCode == SWT.ESC)
                {
                    string += "ESCAPE - keyCode = " + event.keyCode;
                }
                
                //check characters 
                if(event.keyCode >=97 && event.keyCode <=122)
                {
                    string += " " + event.character + " - keyCode = " + event.keyCode;
                }

                //check digit
                if(event.keyCode >=48 && event.keyCode <=57)
                {
                    string += " " + event.character + " - keyCode = " + event.keyCode;
                }
                System.out.println("Test");
                if(!string.equals(""))
                    System.out.println (string);                    
            }

        });

When I focus on some View and enter CTRL+V or some other sequence of keys, then the output is normal:
CTRL - keyCode = 118  - keyCode = 118
And when I focus on some Editor and enter CTRL+V, then stateMask is 0 and second key is ignored...
What could be reason of this?

The PartRenderingEngine also filters KeyDown events to map them to commands (such as Paste), it may be stopping the key down propogating to your code (just guessing I haven't tested this). org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher does most of the work.

Looking at KeyBindingDispatcher I think if the key stroke maps to a command (in this case Paste) and there is an active handler for the command then the key stroke is not propogated. So I guess the editor has a handler for Paste, but the view doesn't.
